# Delayed Jobs not picking up second ActionMailer action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer, delayed-job

My problem is pretty simple, I am trying to delay 2 ActionMailer actions on the same method, this way:

```
@params = params
begin
  ContactMailer.delay.email_application(@params)
  ContactMailer.delay.email_application_confirmation(@params)
end
```

The first one is being sent to the website's admin, the second one to the user submitting the form.

But only the first one is being picked up by `delayed_job` and added to the jobs queue. What's going on with the second one? (I tried to add ``` begin``end ``` for that reason but it didn't change anything).

EDIT: I should mention that, looking at the logs, nothing appears, as if the second line was completely being ignored

Comment: Why the `begin; end`? Do you expect an exception from the mailer?

Answer (score 0):

this fixed it...

```
@params = params
begin
  ContactMailer.delay.email_application(@params)
end
begin
  ContactMailer.delay.email_application_confirmation(@params)
end
```